# Disable States for us-map (newsignature) library

Tags: javascript

I have this map defined using us-map library: https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/

```
$('#map').usmap({
  showLabels: true,
  stateStyles: {fill: '#e57325', stroke: '#fff', color: '#fff'},
  stateSpecificStyles: {
    'OR': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'ID': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'MT': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'WY': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'UT': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'UT': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'NM': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'ND': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'NE': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'MN': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'IA': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'VA': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'WV': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'ME': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'NH': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'VT': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'RI': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'MA': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'SD': {fill: '#F7B213'},
    'AK': {fill: '#F7B213'}
  },
  stateHoverStyles: {fill: '#e6e6e6', color: '#fff'},
  'labelTextStyles': {
      fill: "#555",
      'stroke': 'none',
      'font-weight': 300,
      'stroke-width': 0,
      'font-size': '14px'
  },
  click: function (event, data) {
      window.location.href = '/state/' + abbrState(data.name, 'name').toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
  }
 });
```

The states listed under stateSpecificStyles, I would like to have them disabled so the users can't click on them and the cursor is not set to pointer. I can't seem to see this listed in their documentation.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your CSS:

```
#map {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: initial;
}
```

Comment: This will disable the whole map, I just want to disable certain states.

Comment: Then make your CSS selector more specific such as `#map svg path`

Comment: Targeting a path doesn't look easy, since none of the paths have classes or ids. The only way I can think of doing this is by using :nth-child.

Comment: Maybe this in your JS would work: `'OR': {fill: '#F7B213', style: 'pointer-events:none;cursor:initial;'},`

Comment: Yeah, was looking at the doc, it doesn't seem clear it supports all attributes. nth-child sounds like your best way indeed.